# SQLITE3 close() doesn't close database?

Tags: sqlite, wxwidgets

I am writing a little database application using wxWidgets 2.9.5 + windows 7 + MSVC 2008 + sqlite3. I noticed that when I create a new database using: sqlite3_open16() and close it afterwards and then try to delete the freshly created database file, that I get an error: 32 from wxRemove() ( couldn't be removed (error 32: another process is using your file ...)

After reading some of the other questions in the forum I downloaded a file unlocker from: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ and checked what other process, is using my file - surprise - non but my own. After freeing the handles with the software I was able to delete the created database with my programm.

My question: How do I check if a file that I want to delete is opend, hijack the handle and close it? / How do I force the sqlite3 api do acutally deallocate it's ressources as claimend here: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html

Comment: I found the problem. I could delete everything without problem after I changed the currentworking directory with wxSetWorkingDirectory(); -> just in case anyone else has this problem

Answer (score 0):

> I found the problem. I could delete everything without problem after I
>   changed the current working directory with wxSetWorkingDirectory(); ->
>   just in case anyone else has this problem